# h:message for JSF composite component with input

Tags: jsf, composite-component

I'm often running into issues / unknowns regarding composite component behaviour for their intended use as value holders (with inputs).  To summarise, where I have a composite component declared in the following way:

```
<cc:interface>
   <cc:attribute name="value" required="true"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
   <h:inputText id="textInput" value="#{cc.attrs.value} />
</cc:implementation>
```

and used:

```
<my:componentWithInput id="foo" value="#{someBean.value} />
```

My issue is with IDs. If I want to target the element with `h:message`, I'm not sure what structure I should be following, where ultimately what I want to achieve is:

```
<h:message for="foo" styleClass="error" />
<my:componentWithInput id="foo" value="#{someBean.value} />
```

I appreciate that given composite components are naming containers, this doesn't work, since the generated id of 'foo' in this case would resolve to the composite component id and not to the input.

I've been looking into `cc:editableValueHolder` etc. but am unclear as to the appropriate way to achieve this.

EDIT: To make my question more clear, I'm looking for a way of giving the component an ID, and for it to provide the input contained within with this ID, such that I can reference it externally without having to know (or indeed provide via an attribute) the ID of the input itself.  In other words to emulate the behaviour of `<h:inputText />` as a standalone component itself.  If this is impossible, or that I misunderstand the purpose of composite components by this, then I am happy to accept that.